# Issues installing updates with disk encryption

Tags: updates, encryption

I am quite new to linux and have just installed Kubuntu 15.04. I have been trying to install available update packages using the MUON Update Manager, however when the progress bar gets to about 25% the program stalls permanently (with the process: systemd (amd64), being displayed above the progress bar). My question is: Has the fact that I selected the encrypted lvm option during the OS installation, affected my ability to install updates via the update manager as seems to be the case according to the various forums I have been browsing? And, if so, I would appreciate suggestions as to how to proceed.

Thanks.

In response to muru's edit request:

Both `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` yielded:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Upon running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` both the `apt-update` and `apt-upgrade` processes completed succesfully, albeit asking for swap disk decryption passwords multiple times (`Please enter passphrase for disk kubuntu--vg-swap_1 (cryptswap1) on none!`) which leads me to believe that the GUI Update Manager isn't able to function with disk encryption ? Is this to your knowledge a known issue, must one perform updates/upgrades via the command line always in this situation?

Thanks for the response btw and apologies for lack of conciseness in the question.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in a terminal and [edit] your question to add the output, please.

Comment: I think it's worth filing a bug report and let the devs know. `ubuntu-bug muon` should do that for you. If it's a known bug, they'll let you know that too.